# C# is there a way to use a method like a constructor

Tags: c#, xml

I'm a newb so I apologize if this is a dumb question.  I have bound my interface to the fields of a class I built.  I initiated class as a List of type T, now I am trying to increment the assignment of fields to an index of the list.

My code looks something like this.
my class:

```
class MyClass
{  
    public string ID { get; set; }  // I want these to increment
    public string MyVar { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        this.ID = "";
        this.MyVar = "";
    }

    public MyClass (string id, string myvar)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.MyVar = myvar      
    }

    public static List<MyClass> Query(string datasource)
    {
        XElement data = XElement.Load(datasource);
        List<MyQuiz> query = (from d in data.Descendants("Object")
                              select new MyQuiz((string)d.Element("ID"),
                                                (string)d.Element("MyVar")
                             )).ToList();
               return query;
    }

    public static List<MyClass> Assign (List<MyClass> assign, int i)
    {
        i++

        //Can't do this because it's static, need another way!
        this.ID = assign[i].ID;
        this.MyVar = assign[i].MyVar;
    }
```

The initiating code

```
int i = 0;
List<MyClass> myClass = new List<MyClass>();
myClass = MyClass.Query("data.xml");
MyClass.Assign(myClass, i);
```

and the xml

```
<root>
    <Object>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <MyVar>TESTING</MyVar>
    </Object>
<root>
```

Everything works except the Assign method, any suggestions?

Comment: there's no semi-colon (;) after your i increment and there's a } missing at the end of your method

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. What is the purpose of the `Assign` method?

Comment: What does Assign method suppose to do?

Comment: Any reason your `Assign` method is static? You cannot access non-static properties from a static context.

Comment: It's purpose is to increment the index of List and assign those values to the field.

Comment: I tried to make non static but then I have to make a new instance of the class, Don't I?  That would reset the data, giving me nothing to increment.

Comment: I see that your `Query()` returns a list of MyQuiz objects. Have you checked that list to ensure that Query is working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your type has a state it will be better to create an instance of this class before using it.
Just remove static keywords from the methods and then use the following code:

```
List<MyClass> myClass = new List<MyClass>();
MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass();
myClass = myClassInstance.Query("data.xml");
myClassInstance.Assign(myClass, i);
```

Comment: it won't let me use "Assign" with an instance.

Comment: @evilsushi you need to remove the `static` from the method `Assign`

Comment: This solved my issue, I created model view then created an instance of the class, I was then able to bind to it.  I still am having problems incrementing the index but I think the problem is I am still struggling the with the proper syntax for the iCommand interface.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do something like this:

```
public static List<MyClass> Assign (MyClass target, List<MyClass> assign, int i)
{
    i++;
    target.ID = assign[i].ID;
    target.MyVar = assign[i].MyVar;
}
```

Which will replace the values in the first instance of `MyClass` with the ones in the i'th instance of your `List<MyClass>`

It's a tad hard to tell though because it's not obvious what you're trying to achieve here. It doesn't look like there's any reason not to just re-instantiate the object with the new parameters.

Comment: My GUI is bound to the fields.  The first time I initialize the class I fill it with LINQ data now I want to set the first member (index 0) to the field.  Later I want to just run "Assign" and increment to index 1 and set those values to my fields so then they are reflected in my Bound GUI elements.

Comment: I understood the words but I've still got no idea what you're actually trying to do or why. You need to provide a little more context on how you're using the code you've got and what you're ultimately trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to initialize the Id:

```
public static List<MyClass> Assign (List<MyClass> assign, int i)
{         
     for(int j=0;j<assign.Count;j++){
         assign[j].ID = i;
         i++
     }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like the original behavior

Comment: @evilsushi said he wants to increment the index, so ... But I agree with you and +1 you, we are far from the original code!

Comment: It's a guessing game - OP's requeriments are somewhat "vage" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>();

public static List<MyClass> Assign (List<MyQuiz> assign, int i)
{
    myClassList.Add(new MyClass(assign[i].ID, assign[i].MyVar));
    return myClassList;
}
```

Based on your question, this is what you're looking for. Create a new instance of MyClass, add it to the list, and assign field values based on i.

Edit: Added a public static list of MyClass to your class. This should add the item to a new static list in the class and return the list. It's unclear since there are two class names in the question and seem to be some type issues in the code.

Comment: assign is not an empty list as it is initialized with `myClass = MyClass.Query("data.xml");`

Comment: all my errors went away but no data seems to be getting there.

Comment: @Thomas assign doesn't need to be an empty list. But this code will add duplicate entries into the list.

Comment: @evilsushi Is your problem that your list is empty? Because I didn't look at your Query code, but I imagined you expected that to be populating the list....so everything should already be assigned to the list. Right?